# How to cache intermediate results when rendering with parameters?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

With RMarkdown, I try to render a parametrized report for different values of a parameter. The Rmd file use caching.

The caching works as intended if I knit in RStudio, with the knit button : cache built at first, then used at each successive knitting, even if I change the parameter value in the YAML header.

But when looping with my parameters values and using `rmarkdown::render()` the cache is rebuilt at each iteration.

The `test.Rmd` file

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
params:
  id: 0
date: "23/10/2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Test `r params$id`

```{r cars, cache=TRUE}
## open and work on large file (simulate)
test <- mtcars
Sys.sleep(10)
```
````

And the rendering script : `render.R`

```r
library(rmarkdown)
library(tidyverse)

1:5 %>% 
  walk(function(x) render("test.Rmd",
                          params = list(id = x),
                          output_file = paste0("file", x, ".html")))
```

The script takes 5 * 10 seconds to run instead of about 10 seconds.

What did I do wrong? How to use the cache?

Comment: I’m guessing that changing the parameters invalidates the caches because it’s impossible to prove in general that the cached content isn’t affected by the parameters. This is a fundamental property. Maybe Knitr has a way of indicating that a chunk is independent of parameters but, short of that, this is unsolvable.

Comment: Thanks for the clue @KonradRudolph ; I'll dig into that

Comment: It seems different parameters should not invalidate the cache ; see https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1624

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Can you try whether Yihui’s suggestion works? I.e. adding `cache.extra = params` to the chunk options? This *shouldn’t be necessary* as far as I understand but it might help diagnosing the issue.

Comment: with `cache.extra = params` the cache is used when knitting (RStudio knit button) multiple times with the same parameter value, but is invalidated when we manually change the value in the YAML header ; as intended. When using `render()` still never used (thats also as intended)

Comment: Thanks for testing. Bizarre. This feels like a bug.

Comment: Yes, maybe. I'll add an issue in the project repository. Thanks anyway @KonradRudolph.

Comment: Issue added https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1679

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with parameters, which can be shown by the minimized reprex below (`test.Rmd`) by taking out the parameters (and the irrelevant **tidyverse**):

````
---
title: "Untitled"
---

```{r, cache=TRUE}
Sys.sleep(10)
```
````

Then run

```r
for (i in 1:5) rmarkdown::render(
  "test.Rmd", output_file = paste0("file", i, ".html")
)
```

The problem comes from `output_file`, which changes in each iteration. For R Markdown documents, the output filename determines the **knitr** chunk option `fig.path`. For example, when `output_file = "file1.html"`, `fig.path` is set to `file1_files/html/`.

When any chunk option of a code chunk changes, **knitr** will invalidate its cache. In your case, `fig.path` invalidated the cache each time. To avoid that, you have to stabilize this option, e.g.,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
---

```{r, cache=TRUE, fig.path='test_files/html/'}
Sys.sleep(2)
```
````

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand that changing the output_file had impact on fig.path and then chunk caching. (And thanks for this great tool!)